# Silverlight MVVM vs NON-MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

I'm about to optimize a silver light application, and it's made with some MVVM and some regular code(code behind) so my question is, should i continue the MVVM pattern, or should i just go all out on code behind, logic classes and so on?

The application is just for showing statistics, so it's receiving some data from an SQL DB, and then showing them in some charts and so on.. so thats really it..

what do you think MVVM or no MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this application, I think MVVM is an overkill, I have used MVVM thoroughly and I can tell you, it is great when you have those typical CRUD scenarios but for an application such as this, I would go with Non-MVVM

Comment: well.. the application might grow a bit.. so show some other data, with 3 different screens.. which all shows different data.. so.. well how big should the application be before i need MVVM?

Comment: Your last question can't be answered in any universe, it is for the Software Architect to decide that on a per-project basis. You have to know that early moderate decisions are better than late excellent decisions. i.e. If you decided later to transform your design from any to another option, that could be time-consuming.